# "Unmatched Route" when I start a React Native application with Expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I'm new to React Native, and I just trying to start my React Native app with Expo, and instantly says: "Unmatched Route - Page could not be found" when I just access on Metro Bundler through the Expo Go app.

On-Screen Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqTot.png)

on **App.tsx**:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './app/Navigation/Navigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Navigation />
  );
}
```

on **app/Navigation/Navigation.tsx**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import StartScreen from '../pages/StartScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="StartScreen">
        <Stack.Screen name="StartScreen" component={StartScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

on **app/pages/Home.tsx**:

```
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../utilities/styles';
import React from 'react';
const packageJson = require('../../package.json');

const appVersion = packageJson.version;

const Home = () => {

    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

    const themeContainerStyle = colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightContainer : styles.darkContainer;
    const themeTextStyle = colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightTextTheme : styles.darkTextTheme;

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[styles.container, themeContainerStyle]}>
            <View style={[styles.contentCenter]}>
                <Text style={[themeTextStyle, styles.h3]}>Home Page</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.contentEnd]}>
                <Text style={[themeTextStyle]}>Ver: {appVersion}</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

on **app/pages/StartScreen.tsx**:

```
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../utilities/styles';
import React from 'react';
const packageJson = require('../../package.json');

const appVersion = packageJson.version;

const StartScreen = () => {

    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

    const themeContainerStyle = colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightContainer : styles.darkContainer;
    const themeTextStyle = colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightTextTheme : styles.darkTextTheme;

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[styles.container, themeContainerStyle]}>
            <View style={[styles.contentCenter]}>
                <Text style={[themeTextStyle, styles.h3]}>Project Spectrum</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.contentEnd]}>
                <Text style={[themeTextStyle]}>Ver: {appVersion}</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default StartScreen;
```

I just tried add my Entry Point route into the app.json but even that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it would show "Unmatched Route" when first starting the app in Expo Go, but when navigating between tabs it showed the screen. I found [this comment on a similar GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/router/issues/457#issuecomment-1615255402). Changing the file name for the first screen back to "index.js" and clearing the cache with **npx expo start -c** fixed it for me.